Error while importing data into PostgreSQL with PgAdmin
I'm encountering an issue while importing data into a new PostgreSQL database created in PgAdmin with this code
CREATE DATABASE alphashop
  WITH
  OWNER = postgres
  ENCODING = 'UTF8'
  LOCALE_PROVIDER = 'libc'
  CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
  IS_TEMPLATE = False;

I've extracted the schema and data files from my working database with this code produced by pgadmin
/usr/local/pgsql-16/pg_dump --file "/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/myemail_gmail.com/schema.sql" --host "172.21.0.2" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --role "postgres" --format=p --encoding "UTF8" --schema-only --verbose "alphashop"

/usr/local/pgsql-16/pg_dump --file "/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/myemail_gmail.com/data.sql" --host "172.21.0.2" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --role "postgres" --format=p --encoding "UTF8" --data-only --inserts --verbose "alphashop"

then I run the schema.sql file through the pgadmin query tool, I get the schema created with no problems but if I run the data.sql file in the query tool immediately afterwards, I start getting these errors:
ERROR: relation "scontrini" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(totale) FROM scontrini WHERE codfi...
^
QUERY: SELECT SUM(totale) FROM scontrini WHERE codfid = NEW.codfid
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function public.tr_inserisci_coupon() line 4 at SQL statement

SQL state: 42P01

If I check the schema I created by restoring the schema.sql file, I see that the 'scontrini' table was created correctly in the db. I also paid attention to the order of execution of the scripts by proceeding first with schema.sql and then with data.sql.
Additional Information:

I'm using PgAdmin 4.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.
I'm using PostgreSQL 14.
pgadmin4 and postgresql run into Docker

This is the docker-compose.yml I used:
version: '3.3'

networks: 
  ntpgsql:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.21.0.0/24

services:
  pgsql:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: postgresql
    volumes: 
      - psdb-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks: 
      ntpgsql:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.2
    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5433 
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypass
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: pgadmin4
    
    networks:
      ntpgsql:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.3
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=True
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=myemail@gmail.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=mypass


volumes:
  psdb-volume:


SOLUTION
The problem was related to the way I was backing up the data in the data.sql file through pgadmin.
It was enough to disable the Triggers among the dump options in pgadmin to solve the problem.

Most likely you're connected to the wrong database, or using UPPER case characters in the object names.

@FrankHeikens I checked but everything is ok
